# Magento 2: Proper way to utilize "ajax:addToCart" event

Tags: magento2, javascript, addtocart

I found the following codes in **/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/web/js/catalog-add-to-cart.js** at around line 100, when I was trying to find ways to add some custom JS handling after successfully adding a product to the cart, on a **Magento Open Source 2.2.5**:

```
$(document).trigger('ajax:addToCart', {
    'sku': form.data().productSku,
    'form': form,
    'response': res
});
```

I believe this is the event I could utilize to achieve what I wanted. I have tried to write a handler like this inside the **/product/view/form.phtml** template:

```
<script>
require([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    $('document').on('ajax:addToCart', function (event, data) {
        console.log(data.form.data());
    });
});
</script>
```

But nothing showed up in the console. So I am guessing there is something wrong with the binding of handler and triggering of the event. Could someone please help to give an example on how I could make use of the event?

Comment: In my case, i have no value inside form.data().productSku.
Any idea about that?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/159022)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, well, in the original code there is `$(document)`, where `document` is js variable, but in your code you have something like `$('document')`.

This is an attempt to select some DOM element I suppose, but maybe this selector is actually returning no selection and therefore nothing happens?

Final code is :

```
$(document).on('ajax:addToCart', function (event, data) {
    console.log(event);
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Don't worry, it happens to all of us.